# Figure out if Solid State Drive is being used as cache

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, fedora, cache

I am using Fedora 20 OS.

I am trying to see if my SSD is being used as Cache for fast reads.

So far I check to see if the SSD is mounted so I did:

```
sudo lshw | grep -A 10 SSD
```

and I got:

```
 product: SAMSUNG SSD PM83
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: CXM1
             serial: S0XLNSAD131996
             size: 29GiB (32GB)
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
  *-power UNCLAIMED
```

so SSD does not seem to be mounted

Moreover, I check the status of virtual memory using `vmstat` , and I have:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 2  0 410524 3870920 6755392 688964    0    0    74    42    2    1  7  1 87  5
```

So it doesn't seem like there is 32 GB of cache which should be provided by the SSD, am I correct?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's not as simple as that. You need to configure bcache to use the SSD as cache. Some documentation here: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/Documentation/bcache.txt . I would recommand you backing up your data and being sure of what you're doing since if something goes wrong you could loose all of it.

Comment: @piernov I could lose what? the SSD or my personal data?

Comment: @piernov Also how can I check to see if it is not being used for cache already before I go ahead and do something like what you linked me? how can I be sure that it is not working before I go ahead and try to fix it?